# Export magento products with categories from older installation to newer installation (import)

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have a website which is currently running with alot of users and products ( around 12,000 ) on Magento 1.6 and i want to convert and redesign this website with custom functionality on Magento 1.7.

I exported all the products from older version but there is no option for category export?

I am stuck with categorie export option. I tried many source but nothing helps me. Many people said there is option for exporting categories on magento ( > system > export/import > Data Profile )

Or

Is it possible to import/export database tables from lower version to upper version for products with categories. ( linked on newer version ) No, need to assign.

I Installed new version ( magento 1.7 ) on server. I want to export all products with their categories from previous version to this installation.

There are alot of extensions which are paid for this but i am interested in open source.